# Why does ARIMA model script does not work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.9

Well, I've got ARIMA model for GDP prediction and it does not work at all

I already asked question here and I was told that my values were wrong. I rechecked them and they are correct, but the code still doesn't work

```
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA

data = {
 "Date": ["2010-01-01", "2010-01-04", "2010-01-07", "2010-01-10", "2011-01-01", "2011-01-04", "2011-01-07", "2011-01-10", "2012-01-01", "2012-01-04", "2012-01-07", "2012-01-10", "2013-01-01", "2013-01-04", "2013-01-07", "2013-01-10", "2014-01-01", "2014-01-04", "2014-01-07", "2014-01-10", "2015-01-01", "2015-01-04", "2015-01-07", "2015-01-10", "2016-01-01", "2016-01-04", "2016-01-07", "2016-01-10", "2017-01-01", "2017-01-04", "2017-01-07", "2017-01-10", "2018-01-01", "2018-01-04", "2018-01-07", "2018-01-10", "2019-01-01", "2019-01-04", "2019-01-07", "2019-01-10", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-04", "2020-01-07", "2020-01-10"],
    "GDP(valid)": [14.764, 14.98, 15.141, 15.309, 15.351, 15.557, 15.647, 15.842, 16.068, 16.207, 16.319, 16.42, 16.648, 16.728, 16.953, 17.192, 17.197, 17.518, 17.804, 17.912, 18.063, 18.279, 18.401, 18.435, 18.525, 18.711, 18.892, 19.089, 19.28, 19.438, 19.692, 20.037, 20.328, 20.58, 20.798, 20.917, 21.104, 21.384, 21.694, 22.092, 21.706, 19.913, 21.647, 22.024],
    "Unemployment": [4.85, 4.84, 4.836, 4.828, 4.82, 4.81, 4.8, 4.79, 4.78, 4.77, 4.76, 4.75, 4.74, 4.73, 4.72, 4.718, 4.71, 4.7, 4.696, 4.69, 4.683, 4.677, 4.67, 4.67, 4.657, 4.65, 4.64, 4.635, 4.628, 4.62, 4.61, 4.65, 4.6, 4.588, 4.58, 4.57, 4.56, 4.548, 4.536, 4.524, 4.51, 4.5, 4.49, 4.48],
    "Interest rate": [3.71, 3.49, 2.78, 2.86, 3.46, 3.21, 2.42, 2.04, 2.03, 1.82, 1.64, 1.7, 1.95, 2, 2.71, 2.74, 2.76, 2.62, 2.5, 2.28, 2, 2.16, 2.22, 2.19, 1.92, 1.75, 1.56, 2.13, 2.44, 2.26, 2.24, 2.37, 2.76, 2.92, 2.92, 3.03, 2.65, 2.33, 1.8, 1.79, 1.37, 0.68, 0.65, 0.86],
    "Import volume": [563.166, 588.05, 604.7, 619.5, 652.4, 674.9, 682.4, 688.3, 698.7, 696.6, 688.1, 670, 688, 688, 670, 694, 710, 723.2, 720.1, 722.4, 700, 697.3, 694.3, 680.06, 666.2, 674.9, 686.2, 693, 712.6, 730.35, 724.18, 754.28, 770.353, 773.616, 785.58, 791.5, 782.6, 785.9, 776.96, 760.26, 733.363, 612.47, 709.62, 757.57],
    "Export volume": [1759.9, 1819.7, 1877.2, 1972.1, 2040.4, 2116.1, 2156.8, 2150.1, 2190, 2215.6, 2227.7, 2237.5, 2255.9, 2261.4, 2285.1, 2349.2, 2343.6, 2395.2, 2399.2, 2376.2, 2299, 2300.4, 2260.7, 2222.3, 2182, 2222, 2270, 2268.4, 2339.7, 2349.7, 2384.5, 2479.1, 2517.3, 2562.2, 2535.5, 2537.4, 2544.1, 2545.4, 2532.4, 2531.9, 2416.1, 1811.3, 2106.6, 2266.4],
    "State. Expenditure": [3710.5, 3745.7, 3792.44, 3809.8, 3811.3, 3849.4, 3783.8, 3786.5, 3774.3, 3772.8, 3777.3, 3769.5, 3758.8, 3776, 3773.7, 3772.4, 3819.4, 3876, 3931.6, 3926.6, 3970.2, 3990.8, 4011.9, 4050.4, 4084.3, 4101.6, 4150.5, 4175.5, 4119.2, 4195.5, 4254, 4320.4, 4398.5, 4453.8, 4512.2, 4593.4, 4688.5, 4736.9, 4776.8, 4792, 4870.1, 8830, 7114.8, 5863.6],
    "Inflation": [2.6, 2.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.6, 3.2, 3.6, 3.5, 2.9, 2.3, 1.4, 2.2, 1.6, 1.1, 2, 1, 1.6, 2, 2, 1.7, -0.1, -0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.4, 1.1, 0.8, 1.6, 2.5, 2.2, 1.7, 2, 2.1, 2.5, 2.9, 2.5, 1.6, 2, 1.8, 1.8, 2.5, 0.3, 1, 1.2],
}


df_diff = df.diff().dropna()


p, d, q = 1, 1, 1


freq = 'QS'


model = ARIMA(df_diff["GDP(valid)"], order=(p, d, q), exog=df_diff[["Unemployment", "Interest rate", "Import volume", "Export volume", "State. Expenditure", "Inflation"]])


model_fit = model.fit()


forecast_start = pd.to_datetime('2021-01-01')
forecast_end = pd.to_datetime('2021-04-01')


exog_forecast = df.loc[forecast_start:forecast_end, ["Unemployment", "Interest rate", "Import volume", "Export volume", "State. Expenditure", "Inflation"]].diff().dropna()


forecast_diff = model_fit.get_forecast(steps=len(exog_forecast), exog=exog_forecast)
forecast_values = forecast_diff.predicted_mean.cumsum() + df["GDP(valid)"].iloc[-1]


forecast_index = pd.date_range(start=forecast_start, end=forecast_end, freq=freq)
forecast_df = pd.DataFrame(forecast_values.values, index=forecast_index, columns=["GDP Forecast"])
print(forecast_df)
```

And I always get the same error

```
/Users/yermadimukashov/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/base/tsa_model.py:473: ValueWarning: A date index has been provided, but it has no associated frequency information and so will be ignored when e.g. forecasting.
  self._init_dates(dates, freq)
/Users/yermadimukashov/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/base/tsa_model.py:473: ValueWarning: A date index has been provided, but it has no associated frequency information and so will be ignored when e.g. forecasting.
  self._init_dates(dates, freq)
/Users/yermadimukashov/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/base/tsa_model.py:473: ValueWarning: A date index has been provided, but it has no associated frequency information and so will be ignored when e.g. forecasting.
  self._init_dates(dates, freq)
/Users/yermadimukashov/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/statespace/sarimax.py:966: UserWarning: Non-stationary starting autoregressive parameters found. Using zeros as starting parameters.
  warn('Non-stationary starting autoregressive parameters'
/Users/yermadimukashov/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/statespace/sarimax.py:978: UserWarning: Non-invertible starting MA parameters found. Using zeros as starting parameters.
  warn('Non-invertible starting MA parameters found.'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/yermadimukashov/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 31, in <module>
    forecast = model_fit.get_forecast(steps=len(exog_forecast), exog=exog_forecast)
  File "/Users/yermadimukashov/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/statespace/mlemodel.py", line 3417, in get_forecast
    return self.get_prediction(start=self.nobs, end=end,
  File "/Users/yermadimukashov/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/statespace/mlemodel.py", line 3340, in get_prediction
    self.model._get_prediction_index(start, end, index))
  File "/Users/yermadimukashov/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/base/tsa_model.py", line 836, in _get_prediction_index
    return get_prediction_index(
  File "/Users/yermadimukashov/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/base/tsa_model.py", line 389, in get_prediction_index
    raise ValueError("Prediction must have `end` after `start`.")
ValueError: Prediction must have `end` after `start`.
```

Comment: `exog_forecast`is empty because your original dataframe is not containing the datetime range `forecast_start:forecast_end`. Thus `len(exog_forecast)` is zero which leads to the above error

Comment: I did not really understand what you mean. Could you show code lines to change?

Comment: Well, I tried to fix it and I still get the same error message. Code and error :https://docs.google.com/document/d/1s8DdF_jANqtq6EFlUKgOykv6bpQ_4deUx13LvDIRCrk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @algebruh could you have a look, please?